# Reorder Lines in a Text File (Loop Assistance)

Tags: python

A have a fairly large text file that I need to reorder the lines such as....

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Reordered to look like this

```
line2
line1
line3
```

File will continue with more lines and the same reordering must occur.  I'm stuck and need a loop to do this.  Unfortunately, I have hit a speed bump.

```
with open('poop.txt') as fin, open('clean330.txt', 'w') as fout:
     for line in fin:
          ordering = [1, 0, 2]
          for idx in ordering: # Write output lines in the desired order.
               fout.write(line)
```

Comment: Have you looked at your output?  All you're doing is writing out each line of input three times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of lines is a multiple of 3:

```
with open('poop.txt') as fin, open('clean330.txt', 'w') as fout:
    while True:
        try:
            in_lines = [next(fin) for _ in range(3)]
            fout.write(in_lines[1])
            fout.write(in_lines[0])
            fout.write(in_lines[2])
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Comment: I wish this type of knowledge would come natural to myself.  Great job.

Answer (score 1):

You can read in 3 lines at a time.

```
with open('poop.txt') as fin, open('clean330.txt', 'w') as fout:
    line1 = True
    while line1:
        line1 = fin.readline()
        line2 = fin.readline()
        line3 = fin.readline()
        fout.write(line2)
        fout.write(line1)
        fout.write(line3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the function `grouper` in itertools documentation.  You then need to do something like:

```
for lines in grouper(3, fin, '')
    for idx in [1, 0, 2]:
        fout.write(lines[idx])
```

You haven't specified what you want to do if the input file doesn't have an exact multiple of 3 lines.  This code uses blanks.

Comment: Your code isn't using the `itertools` recipe for a `grouper()` function properly.

Answer (score 1):

For a single line swap the code can be like:

```
with open('poop.txt') as fin, open('clean330.txt', 'w') as fout: 
     for idx, line in enumerate(fin):
          if idx == 0:
              temp = line # Store for later
          elif idx == 1:
              fout.write(line) # Write line 1
              fout.write(temp) # Write stored line 0
          else:
              fout.write(line) # Write as is
```

For repeated swaps the condition can be e. g. `idx % 3 == 0` depending on the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it that makes use of a couple of Python utilities and a helper function to make things relatively easy. If the number of lines in the file isn't an exact multiple of the length of the group you want to reorder, they're left alone—but that could easily be changed that if you desired.

The `grouper()` helper function is similar—but *not* identical—to the recipe with one with same name that's shown in in the `itertools` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from operator import itemgetter


def grouper(n, iterable):
    ''' s -> (s0,s1,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,...s2n-1), (s2n,s2n+1,...s3n-1), ... '''
    FILLER = object()  # Value which couldn't be in data.
    for result in zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n, fillvalue=FILLER):
        yield tuple(v for v in result if v is not FILLER)


ordering = 1, 0, 2
reorder = itemgetter(*ordering)
group_len = len(ordering)

with open('poop.txt') as fin, open('clean330.txt', 'w') as fout:
     for group in grouper(group_len, fin):
        try:
            group = reorder(group)
        except IndexError:
            pass  # Don't reorder potential partial group at end.
        fout.writelines(group)
```